# Define a dynamic drop down list with a function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I know this question has already been asked and I have spent several hours going through online messages and tutorials but I am not able to make this work: I am trying to define a function so to report the selected option in a dynamically defined drop down list. This is the code:

```
function disease_dropdown($var, $listsql) { // $var is the name of the field 

$db_connect = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);          
$listres = mysqli_query($db_connect, $listsql);
$menu = '<option selected value="">--- Select ---</option>\n';

while ($listrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listres)) {
    if ( isset($var) && $var == $listrow['cat_id'] ) {
    $selected = $listrow['cat_id'];
    $menu .= '
  <option selected value="' . $selected . '">' . $listrow['disease'] . '</option>';
    }

    else {            
    $menu .= '
  <option value="' . $listrow['cat_id'] . '">' . $listrow['disease'] . '</option>';  
    }

}   
return $menu;
```

}

The function is working Ok, BUT I am not able to keep the value in the selected option, and I do not know why.

listsql = "SELECT cat_id disease FROM disease ORDER BY cat_id ASC"

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: You should begin by separating your db-related code from your view-constructing code. You will see clearer and your bug will probably magically disappear by itself.

Comment: your comment says $var is the name of the field, but this line 
if ( isset($var) && $var == $listrow['cat_id'] ) {
seems to suggest that $var is the value of the field.  But if it truely is the name of the field then your comparison is never going to work and nothing will be selected

Comment: @lonewolf217: very good point ! But how can I reference the value of the field (in this case <select name="$var" >) ? Whn I try $value = $_POST['var'] I get un undefined index var message...I guess this has to do with the scope of the variable ?

Comment: $_POST should be global.  I am assuming that "var" is not the name of the select element. If the element is <SELECT NAME='selectelem'> then you would use $_POST['selectelem'] to get the value of it
You can also use this to show what is available in post
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);

Comment: Almost there...no yet though...

Comment: Field name = disease_1 <select name="disease_1"> and i refer to it as $var. Now when I put in the function $value=$_POST['var'] or even $value=$_POST['$var'] I get an undefined index message. BUT, when I state $value=$_POST['disease_1'] function works (!) how can I reference correctly disease_1 that is the <select> element name, so that I do not have to recode it ? Thanks a lot for the patience...